# Django messages with inheritance

Tags: python, django

I'm having problems with [Messages Framework of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/messages/). I have the following classes:

```
class A(FormView):
    ...

class B(A):
    success_url = '/success/a'
    ...

class C(A):
    success_url = '/success/b'
    ...
```

When I try to use the [Messages Framework of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/messages/) doing the following, I get no results:

```
class A(SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    ...

class B(A):
    success_url = '/success/a'
    success_message = 'success a'
    ...

class C(A):
    success_url = '/success/b'
    success_message = 'success b'
    ...
```

But, when a use like this I get the messages working:

```
class A(FormView):
    ...

class B(SuccessMessageMixin, A):
    success_url = '/success/a'
    success_message = 'success a'


class C(SuccessMessageMixin, A):
    success_url = '/success/b'
    success_message = 'success b'
    ...
```

I get a lot of classes that is a child of class A. Someone know how can I use Messages Framework with inheritance?

Comment: Please add more code from your form views. Are you overriding `form_valid()` and not calling `super`?

Comment: You're such a Genius. That was exactly what was happening. Can you post a answer, so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SuccessMessageMixin` overrides `form_valid()` and calls `super(SuccessMessageMixin, self).form_valid()`.

From the comments, you are overriding `form_valid()` in your own form views and do not call `super.form_valid()`, thus `SuccessMessageMixin.form_valid()` never gets called.